# americium 241 gamma source

Tags: radiation

the EPA, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium-241) state that Americium-241 decays mainly by alpha radiation. But the equation of decay implies that a gamma ray is produced for every alpha particle produced.

Is that the case? This would make the isotope an equal source of alpha and gamma rays and a thin sheet of aluminium which would stop the alpha particles would then only reduce the radiation by a half

Comment: I seem to recall that more energy is in the alpha than the gamma. Still, it is true that they produce a bit of gamma radiation - I tested it with a gamma-dosimeter on a fire alarm.

Comment: @AndersSandberg The gamma is only 60 keV.

Comment: How is this an astronomy question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no connection made to the study of astronomical objects.

Comment: @JamesK The connection is that we use it as a calibrator.

Comment: There is nothing about use as a calibrator in the question.  It seems to be a "safety" question: if Am241 emits gamma rays how is it made safe by a thin sheet of Al.

Comment: Shouldn't this post be moved to Chem SE?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed. Am-241 is commonly used as a calibration source for hard x-ray and gamma ray astronomy. In addition to its 60 keV gamma ray, it also emits Np L x-rays.